# Whats the best bulk email sender for windows or linux?

Tags: windows, linux, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop Bulk-Emailer Suggestion?](https://superuser.com/questions/34417/desktop-bulk-emailer-suggestion)

I want to send email to a list of people at a certain interval without getting them detected as spam.

Comment: So... you're spamming?

Comment: Not exactly..... I need to inform a large list of people about an event in our institute.

Comment: In other words, spamming. Might want to check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/34417/desktop-bulk-emailer-suggestion

Comment: That's a lot of diamonds below

Answer (score 0):

You want a proper mailing list manager then.  Mailman is what you're looking for on the linux side.  List management will help you prevent yourself actually being spam too.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider some kind of Groups application provided by a large, multi-national corporation.

If you are part of a large, multi-national corporation, and you follow the anti-spam laws, your email should get through. If you are part of a small organization, consider using Yahoo Groups, the Google equivalent, or similar group management application. Then you can be sure that your emails get through, at least to the end-user's spam filter, and that you can't shoot yourself in the legal foot by unwittingly sending unsolicited emails.